# Android Studio - El sistema no encuentra el archivo especificado. Al compilar por primera vez

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Cree un proy nuevo con la ultima version del ide de androidstudio. Cuando se abre el entorno, me muestra este error en el log y se corta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Probe limpiar la cache, abrir/cerrar, pero no encuentro en google que puede ser el error. Como estoy en windows 10, le puse Ejecutar como admin, pero tampoco funciono.

Comment: Entra a File > Settings y agrega en que ruta se encuentra el Android SDK ("Android SDK Location")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de pelear bastante con esto, identifique que android studio tiene problemas con las cuentas que contienen un " _ ". En el nombre de la cuenta de la pc, ejemplo en mi caso User_.

Por lo que dedusco android tiene problemas con los directorios con guiones o ciertos caracteres. Al menos en mi caso, como mencione fue el guion bajo.

Como no podia modificar eso por motivos, lo resolvi como sigue:

1. Desintalar android studio
2. Eliminar los directorios .android y .graddle
3. Crear una cuenta de usuario y ponerle otro nombre. Ej: cristianB
4. Iniciar sesión en esa cuenta, descargar android studio
5. Cuando inicia seleccionar instalacion personalizada o custom (según el idioma)
6. Seleccionar el directorio de la nueva cuenta de usuario para instalar en esa ubicación. Ej: C:/usuarios/cristianB
7. Siguiente y esperar que descargue los paquetes y updates
8. Finalizar y abrir el android studio, cree un proyecto y pruebe compilar, ejecutar.

Ojala esto les sirva, yo lo resolvi para windows 10.